# Cypress Defaultcommadtimeout is not working

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

HI I am writing to write a test case and the application is very slow and every step requires wait but i cant use arbitary wait and when i use defaultCommandTimeout its not working
Heres my code:

```
When('I pick {string} from the dropdown', (option) => {
    if (option !== '') {
        cy.get(commonPage.getMatOption(),{ defaultCommandTimeout: 20000})
            .contains(option)
            .scrollIntoView()
            .should('be.visible')
            .click()
    } else {
        cy.get('.cdk-overlay-transparent-backdrop').click({force:true})


    }
});
```

Comment: What's the error message you receive? When does the test fail because the timeout is not increasing?

Answer (score 4):

One thing to try is to add a `.should()` that ensures you have some options loaded.

```js
cy.get(commonPage.getMatOption(), {timeout: 20_000})
  .should('have.length.gt', 0)                      // wait 20s for options to load

cy.get(commonPage.getMatOption())
  .contains(option)
  .scrollIntoView()
  .should('be.visible')
  .click()
```

Also use `{timeout: 20_000}` not `{defaultCommandTimeout: 20_000}` in the options parameter, the `defaultCommandTimeout` is adjusted in config (if that's the way you want to go).

```js
When('I pick {string} from the dropdown', (option) => {
  Cypress.config('defaultCommandTimeout', 20_000)      // or in cypress.config.js
  ...
```